# Difference between deriving from a standard facet and it's _byname version

Tags: c++

I have tried deriving a custom numpunct<> facet from both numpunct<> as well as from numpunct_byname<>. Both give the same results and both approaches work.

The example I tried was to override the do_truename() and do_falsename() virtual methods so as to return their German equivalents "wahr" and "falsch".

deriving from numpunct_byname<> : 
http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/32172a867ab56086

deriving from numpunct<> : 
http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/33e1190c2a783e1a

Both approaches work correctly.

Is there any difference?

How will I know which approach to adopt?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

One version uses default values for the punctuation, while the other will load things from the named locale.

If you don't name the locale, and then override the virtual functions anyway, there will be no difference.

Possibly you could use the `_byname` version directly and name a German locale (in an OS dependent way).